# Tornado-llike plot with two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Related question that uses three varibales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643189/how-to-add-axis-text-in-this-negative-and-positive-bars-differently-using-ggplot) is easier to do.
This should be seemigly simple but I couldn't get it to work. Here's a simple example:

```
test_me<-data.frame(A=c(-1.5,-5.6,-4.6,-7.8,0.98,0.07,-0.32,-0.4,-0.4),
                    B=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"))
```

The kind of plot(not shown to keep the post as concise as possible) I would like to make with `ggplot2` done with `base`:

```
barplot(test_me$A,col=test_me$B,legend=test_me$B)
```

**This gives me the kind of plot I need. However, `barplot` returns duplicated names in the legend and efforts to remove these were futile.** I could use `lattice` or `barchart` but would prefer a solution that either replicates this in `ggplot2` or **removes the duplicated legend entries in `base`'s output.**

Here is one of several things I've tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_me,aes(B,A,fill=B))+geom_col()
```

The above won't work with changes to `position`. How can I best make this plot? I tried to set manual legends with `legend.text` in `barplot` but that removes the "grouping".
**EDIT**:
The solution below might solve the issue but it leads to overlap in bars unlike the base equivalent. I would therefore prefer a solution that uses `base` with elimination of the multiple entries in the legend. In short, how can I have a grouped `barplot` with just two variables and unique legend entries?

```
test_me %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = A, fill = B)) +
  geom_col()
```

> The issue however is that the above solution results in overlap yet the base plot results in three grouped bars(that is the groups appear to be non-overlapping).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused that your question begins with an edit. Are you asking a different question here about that solution? Or does your sample need to change to make it more clear what the problem is? It's not clear to me exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry. Yes, my main question is how to actually have the `barplot` function from `base` return unique legend names. The edit was made after the answer below although I think the `base` plot differs from the `ggplot`.

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? Here's the output i see from the above commands: https://imgur.com/Q2Uncl2 I don't understand what overlap you are talking about. Are you referring to the legend overlapping the bars in the base plot?

Comment: @MrFlick Perhaps the example wasn't the best as they do indeed look the same. In this example, all groups are of consecutive rows hence the lack of overlap. I will close this as resolved. However, how can I have unique legend entries in the base plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give each element a discrete value on the x axis. Try this:

```
test_me %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = A, fill = B)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: I thought of this but somehow didn't test it. However, how can I solve the issue with multiple legend entries in the base plot?

Comment: I don't work much with the base plotting, hopefully someone can help you with that.

Comment: This solution while it does what I need introduces new labels on the x axis which is not really great since I need to keep the labels. I could remove them totally I guess but there should be a way to use two variables(hopefully).

Comment: I'm a little confused - what labels are you referring to when you say you "need to keep the labels"? And what labels are you referring to by "introduces new labels on the x axis"?

Comment: The x axis really is `row.names` . Anyways, it can be removed all the same.

Comment: The base plots however don't overlap but these do.