# Creating a positive negative bar chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a dataframe, x5 and I want to create a positive negative barchart with the data similar to the question from stackoverflow:
[Question from Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643189/how-to-add-axis-text-in-this-negative-and-positive-bars-differently-using-ggplot)

I was attempting on using some of the code which is shown below:

```
ggplot(x5, aes(reorder(x5[, 1], -x5[, 3]), x5[, 3], fill = class))
```

I kept getting the error message below. I guess it's due to the columns being in character or numeric or factor or something.

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): fill = class. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
```

I'd like the first column (Row.names) labels on the y-axis, the 5th column (Name) name title on the positive and negative sides of the axis, depending on whether it is positive or negative ( as shown in the question). I would also like a darker shade at the highest and a lighter shade at the lowest (if possible).

---

dput(x5):

```
structure(list(Row.names = structure(c("X1a", "X2b", "X3c"), class = "AsIs"), Volatility101 = c(40, 
30, 20), `2020-12-08` = c(-15, 
24, 27), cluster = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ONE", 
"TWO", "Three"), class = "factor"), 
    `12m yield` = c("0.12", "0.44", "2.20"), `Price to forecast PE` = c("7", 
    "12", "8")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next approach can guide you to the right path:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
x5$Var <- as.character(x5$Row.names)
#Plot
ggplot(x5,aes(x=Var,y=`2020-12-08`,fill=Name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_text(aes(x=Var,y=ifelse(`2020-12-08`<0,2,-2),
                label=Name),vjust=0.5)+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]